# ios adding navigation before splitview controller

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to add a navigation view controller prior to the user getting to the splitview controller.  I have tried a few ways of changing the root controller when I want to go from navigation controller to splitview controller but I don't seem to be setting the delegate the right way when I do this.

**Code WITHOUT nav view (works perfectly)**:

**AppDelegate**

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

**Code with nav view prior to SplitView**

**AppDelegate**

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 UIViewController* rootController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dummy"];
self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**DummyViewController**

```
AppDelegate *appDelegateTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
appDelegateTemp.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

This takes me from the DummyViewController that I launched into, to the splitview controller which is the initial view controller in Storyboard.  Which is fine however, when I do it this way none of the delegates get called.  This is probably because when changing root controllers, it is not setting the delegates properly.  How can I get this to work the right way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only really non-hacking way to do it is to present a modal view over the split view in the detail view controller

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DummyViewController *dummy = (DummyViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dummy"]; 
[self presentViewController:dummy animated:NO completion:nil];
```

By setting animation to NO, the user does not see the split view loaded behind it.